# Gradle: Documentation: Using JUnit 5: Missing BOM Dependency

Tags: gradle, junit

According to the official JUnit 5 samples: "https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-example-projects" and "https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.9.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle" the BOM dependency "`testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1'))`" should be used:

```
...
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
}
...
```

But looking at the Gradle "Use JUnit 5" documentation: "https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5" this dependency is missing:

```
...
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
}
...
```

Is this a bug or is this done on purpose?

Comment: The Bom one is correct. I thiink the gradle docs are bit outdated. Both will work.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov I think you're right - the only reason why I hesitate migrating to the BOM variant is due to the following statement in the official documentation: "https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-spring-boot": "If your build relies on dependency management support from Spring Boot, you should not import the junit-bom in your build script since that will result in duplicate (and potentially conflicting) management of JUnit dependencies." - so the question is whether there are more pros or cons in the new approach ...